# Setting up an ASP.NET MVC View to work in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

How would I write the following ASP.NET MVC C# code in VB.NET?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"  
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcGridSample
                    .ViewModels.Shared.Grid<Customer, CustomerSearchForm>>" %>
```

Comment: I know this is proably not going to be overly helpful, but you're going to have to learn to read and translate C# - the underlying framework is the same as are the majority of the language constructs - there's nothing wrong with VB (I have variously hopped between the two languages) but I think a good programmer should, at the very least, be able to read stuff in multiple languages (if doing MVC a grasp of javascript is probably highly desirable) even if not able to write confidently

Comment: thanks Murph i didn't expect to got response like this before..
i really appreciate your attention..
I'm a very2 newbie programmer n hope i'll take many lesson from experts like you...
once again thank you very much :)

-dix-

Answer (score 1):

The correct VB Syntax for this line is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MvcGridSample.ViewModels.Shared.Grid(Of Customer, CustomerSearchForm))" %>
```